# How to squash commit when approve merge request, gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two branches `master` and `release` at gitlab.

At release branch, I hope it will only have commit message like: v0.1.0, v0.1.1.

Say after I finished developed v0.1.0, I have have several feature and bugfix commits in `master` say

```
c1. bugfix1
c2. feature1 
c3. feature2
```

I will create merge request in gitlab from `master` to `release`, but I hope to make these three commits into one `v0.1.0`, and squash c1 c2 c3.

Now , in my existing settings, I will have 4 commit messages:

```
Merge breanch 'master' into release
c1
c2
c3
```

Is there a way to squash it when I approve at gitlab so that there message will squash into:

```
 v0.1.0
```

Please note that these two branch are all proteced branches, and if possible I hope there will be **NO** git command on `release` and `master` branch , and only gitlab operations

Answer (score 5):

```
git checkout release
git merge --squash master
git commit -m "Suitable Message of your choice"
```

This will take all the commits from the `master` branch, squash them into 1 commit and then merge it with your `release` branch.

Answer (score 2):

The merge commit *is* only one commit, but it seems you have fallen into the "fast forward" trap. That is, on your merge, `git` has decided that `master` is part of the direct ancestry of `release`, and then just "fast forwarded" your changes on top of `release`. This, then, looks like what you describe.

To solve this, add the `--no-ff` option on your merge:

```
git checkout release
git merge --no-ff master
```

You will, then, have exactly one commit on your `release` branch; you can edit the commit message to contain your release version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) to squash commits.

In your case, it should be git rebase -i HEAD~3.

See http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html

Answer (score 1):

To squash manually
Go to your master branch or the branch you want to merge

```
git reset --soft HEAD~7 (number of commits from the head you want to squash)
git commit -m "squashed commit"
git push
```

This will reset to a number of commits that were in the master branch. And One single commit will be created with all the changes.
PS: If you are facing an automatic squash error you can use this.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are seeing this message on GitLab graphical interface, like this:

[image: Gitlab error message]

Just follow these steps from your MR link:

> Edit > Merge options: uncheck "Squash commits when merge request is
> accepted" option.

After that, merge should happen on Gitlab.

Comment: and how about the squash? "How to squash commit...."